# MySQL Update column data by comparing ID field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

This is my Table
[image]

I want to copy the "date_email2" data for "18458" id to some specific order id like 18460 and 18468. Can anyone please help me what is the easiest way to do it  [image]

I want to copy the red data on blue box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your table is called orders so you can update this like this

```
UPDATE orders
SET date_email2 = (SELECT date_email2 FROM (SELECT * FROM orders) o WHERE id_order = 18458 ORDER By date_email2  DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE id_order  IN (18460 , 18468)
```

Comment: It is showing an error. You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` in MySQL:

```
update mytable t cross join
       (select t2.*
        from mytable t2
        where t2.id_order = 18458
       ) t2
    set t.date_email2 = t2.date_email2
    where t.id_order in (18460, 18468);
```

Comment: Hello,  I tried it. But it says unknowns table t. I just changed "mytable" name in both lines. Please help